# Display flex is not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, centering

I'm trying to do the center alignment for the image in `<div class="product-image-area">` using `display:flex;`

That is working fine on Edge, Firefox and Chrome but not on IE.

**CSS**:

```
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.vertical {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**Fiddle Here**: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynk5ccmp/3/)

Result in Edge,chrome and Firefox
[image]

Result in IE

[image]

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: you can try to display inline-block with width in %

Comment: @JeysinghAnbu you can try to this http://jsfiddle.net/ynk5ccmp/5/

Comment: When you have issues with IE, you should say what version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removed `img-responsive` CSS class from `img` and added `vertical`

```
.horizontal {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

updated [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ynk5ccmp/18/)

Answer (score 3):

Only IE 11 has partial support for flexbox.

On IE you can use `display: table;` for parent and `display: table-cell;` for children with `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.horizontal {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?
I tested this on IE10 and the img is vertically aligned http://jsfiddle.net/ynk5ccmp/13/

Comment: @Mohammed Reza, Thank you, Now width is Ok. But When I change the height both are different heights. the expectation is both in same height. I have attached fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ynk5ccmp/15/

Comment: @JeysinghAnbu Do u want same height on boxes or images?

Comment: Images should be same height